# How Split a dataset into two random halves in weka?

Tags: random, weka, split

I want to split my dataset into two random halves in weka.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea but not using Weka native api. How about use Random Number Generator? `Math.random()` generates numbers from `0` to `1`.

Suppose that we want to split `dataset` into `set1` and `set2`.

```
for every instance in dataset
{
    if Math.random() < 0.5
        put the instance into set1
    else
        put the instance into set2
}
```

I think that this method may generate similar number of instances for the two subset. If you want to generate exactly the same quantities, you may add additional conditions to `if-else`.

Hope this may offer you some inspiration.

Comment: are you sure this way split dataset in 2 random halves? and this codes is run in which software?

Comment: @parmin It's just pseudocode. You may write the java code according to my idea. Theoretically, it works because each instance has `1/2` possibility to be put into either of the two subset.

Comment: thanks ,I'll do it and it was so helpful. do you know how split a dataset by percent for example set1 have 30 percent of data and set2 70 percent?(randomly too)

Comment: @parmin Sorry for the late reply. I think we may get 3/7 subsets by simply changing the parameter to 0.3. How do you think?

Comment: maybe, but I'll do it by another way and can get the answer.If you want I can put the code here.

Comment: this code is in matlab format:                              function [count1 count2] =Retrive(Source,Percent)
    A=(1:1:Source)';
    Z=false(size(A));
    N=round(Percent/100*numel(A));
    index=round(1+ (numel(A)-1).* rand([1 N]));
    Z(index)=true;
    n=nnz(Z);
    while n<N
        index=round(1+ (numel(A)-1).* rand([1 N-n]));
        Z(index)=true;
        n=nnz(Z);
    end
    count1=A(Z); % if Percent is 20 this line get 20%
    count2=A(~Z); % this line get remain 80% of data
end

Comment: @parmin I looked into the code. It works by generating random index and can divide the dataset into two sets based on the given `Percent`. Good!

Comment: @parmin I've already gone through the code you gave me just now. we can not leave multi-line comments here.

Answer (score 3):

I had same question and the answer is too simple. First, you need to randomly shuffle the order of instances with weka filter (Unsupervised-> instances) and then split data set into two parts. You can find a complete explanation at below link:
http://cs-people.bu.edu/yingy/intro_to_weka.pdf

Comment: It may answer the question.But little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand how it works. Since the link may not exist in future

Comment: The link you have included is dead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use first randomize data set in filter , to make it randomly, secondly use, the Remove percentage filter, use first for 30% for testing and save it then reuse it but check the INVERT box so will be the other 70% and save it

so u will have the testing, and training sets randomized and splitted